# Constructing a sequence of random variables that satisfy a certain property

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots$ be a sequence of random variables defined on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$.

Suppose I have that there exists an $\epsilon$ so that $P(\cap_{m=1}^{\infty} \cup_{n\geq m} \{ |X_n >\epsilon \}) >0$. Then there is a $1>\delta>0$ so that $P(\cap_{m=1}^{\infty} \cup_{n\geq m} \{ |X_n >\epsilon \}) >\delta.$ This tells me that for all $m\in \mathbb{N}, \ P(\cup_{n\geq m} \{|X_n|>\epsilon\})>\delta$, this is because $\cap_{m=1}^{\infty} \cup_{n\geq m} \{ |X_n| >\epsilon \}\subset \cup_{n\geq m} \{|X_n|>\epsilon\}$ for all $m\in \mathbb{N}$.

Now there must be infinitely many $n\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $P(\{|X_n|>\epsilon\})>0.$ For if there are finitely many such $n$, we have that if $m=\max\{\text{ those finitely many } n\}$ then $P(\{|X_n|>\epsilon\})=0$.

> I want to define a sequence of random variables $N_k$ on $\Omega$, so that $N_k(\omega)\rightarrow \infty$ for all $\omega\in \Omega$. I also want to construct this sequence so that $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} P(\{|X_{N_k}|>\epsilon \})>0.$

This was my idea:

Define $n_k=\min\{ m\in\mathbb{N}, m\geq k \ : \ P(\{|X_m|>\epsilon\})> \delta 2^{-k}\}$. Such an $n_k$ exists for otherwise $P(\cup_{n=k}^{\infty} \{|X_n|>\epsilon\})\leq \sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\delta2^{-n}\leq \delta$, a contradiction.

Then I would define $N_k(\omega)=\{\begin{array}{c} n_k \text{ if }\omega\in \cup_{m=k}^{\infty} \{X_m>\epsilon\}  \\ n_{k +1} \text{ else}\end{array}.$ This gives that $N_k(\omega) \rightarrow \infty$ for all $\omega\in\Omega$.

However, I don't think these $N_k$ work when it comes to getting $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} P(\{|X_{N_k}|>\epsilon \})>0.$

Any suggestions?